# Private Cloud Server over Internet as MQTT Broker

Tags: cloud, mqtt, vps

I have an IoT project that require various devices to communicate with each other over internet.
For communication purpose I am using MQTT protocol which runs on 1883 port. I do not have access to my router and firewall and hence I cannot open any port specific for this communication.
I tried using cloud service **test.mosquitto.org** and able to use the broker hosted on cloud without making any changes to any router or firewall.
I would like to create my own cloud VPS which host the MQTT broker and all my devices will connect to this server for communication purpose.
I tried searching a lot for hosting my own cloud server but couldn't get any breakthrough till now. I checked lot of tutorials but most of them are focused on creating Cloud Storage server.
Many of them used services from other vendors such as ALA VPS, VPS Wala, etc.

Can some please guide me on how to proceed further by creating a new Cloud VPS?

Comment: Asking for Tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. You need to try and if you get stuck ask a question that explains what you've tried and how it didn't work so somebody can help you fix it.

Comment: I just want a starting point as I am totally new to this networking and servers field. As specified in my question, I searched for many solutions but couldn't find the one I require.

Comment: You just pick a broker and install it on your VPS.